# Add RDD to DataFrame Column PySpark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I want to create a Dataframe with the columns of two RDD's. 
The first is RDD that i get from CSV and second is another RDD with a cluster prediction of each row.

My schema is:

```
customSchema = StructType([ \
StructField("Area", FloatType(), True), \
StructField("Perimeter", FloatType(), True), \
StructField("Compactness", FloatType(), True), \
StructField("Lenght", FloatType(), True), \
StructField("Width", FloatType(), True), \
StructField("Asymmetry", FloatType(), True), \
StructField("KernelGroove", FloatType(), True)])
```

Map my rdd and create the DataFrame:

```
FN2 = rdd.map(lambda x: (float(x[0]), float(x[1]),float(x[2]),float(x[3]),float(x[4]),float(x[5]),float(x[6])))
 df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(FN2, customSchema)
```

And my cluster prediction:

```
result = Kmodel.predict(rdd)
```

So, to conclude i want to have in my DataFrame the rows of my CSV and their cluster prediction at the end.

I tried to add a new column with .WithColumn() but i got nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a common field on both data frame, then join with the key otherwise create a unique Id and join both dataframe to get rows of CSV and their cluster prediction in a single dataframe

Scala code to generate a unique id for each row, try to convert for the pyspark. You need to generate a increasing row id and join them with row id

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, LongType}
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("abc", 2), ("def", 1), ("hij", 3))).toDF("word", "count")
val wcschema = df.schema
val inputRows = df.rdd.zipWithUniqueId.map{
   case (r: Row, id: Long) => Row.fromSeq(id +: r.toSeq)}
val wcID = sqlContext.createDataFrame(inputRows, StructType(StructField("id", LongType, false) +: wcschema.fields))
```

or use sql query

```
val tmpTable1 = sqlContext.sql("select row_number() over (order by count) as rnk,word,count from wordcount")
tmpTable1.show()
```